# Making a 4D plot in R with different x, y, z colors and lengths

Tags: r, 4d, plot3d

I have a 30 x 16 x 9 matrix  that I would like to visualize via a 4-D plot in R.
I have tried `scatter3D()` in packages `plot3d` and `scatterplot3d`.

```
      x <- seq(10, 300, 10)
      y <- seq(5.0, 20.0, 1.0)
      z <- c(seq(0.5, 4, 0.5), 10)
      scatter3D(x, y, z, colvar = data)
```

It always gives error saying that `y` should have same length as `x`.
How do I deal with this? Why do `x`, `y`, `z` have to be equal length? This is so inconvenient.

Comment: To plot a point in 3-dimensional space you need to know the three spatial coordinates of that point, for example, (x, y, z) or (latitude, longitude, altitude). If I just gave you the x coordinate of a point, it's location on the y-z plane could be anywhere. Thus, `scatter3D` requires three spatial coordinates for each point you want to plot. That's why the x, y, and z vectors must be the same length. The answers provide details on how to do this with code.

Comment: ahhhh, I see~~~ x, y, z should correspond to the x, y, z coordinate of each point I am gonna plot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This happens because each point must have three values for this plot. You have 30 values for x, 16 values for y and 9 values for z. With this data, only the first 9 points will have the x-y-z value. In the comments of your question, [eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496488/eipi10) gives a very good explanation about this. An alternative, for example, is to interpolate the data to create the missing values. [More about data interpolation](http://www.datadigitization.com/dagra-in-action/linear-interpolation-with-excel/).

```
library("plot3D")
number_of_points <- 50
xx <- seq(10, 300, 10)
yy <- seq(5.0, 20.0, 1.0)
zz <- c(seq(0.5, 4, 0.5), 10)

xx <- approx(x = xx, method="linear", n=number_of_points, ties = mean)$y
yy <- approx(x = yy, method="linear", n=number_of_points, ties = mean)$y
zz <- approx(x = zz, method="linear", n=number_of_points, ties = mean)$y

scatter3D(xx, yy, zz)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You say you have a matrix, but what you have is three vectors. You first need to create the "matrix" (here we will make a data.frame named `df` using `expand.grid`):

```
x <- seq(10, 300, 10)
y <- seq(5.0, 20.0, 1.0)
z <- c(seq(0.5, 4, 0.5), 10)

df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y, z = z)
```

Then we can plot using the `scatter3d` function from the `car` package using either method:

```
car::scatter3d(x ~ y + z, data = df)
car::scatter3d(df$x, df$y, df$z)
```

[image: 3d plot]